# How to get the most recently image in a folder?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

How can I get the most recent image that was added to a folder and save that image file path to a variable? I have checked on here (stack overflow) but don't see a post that specifically answers my questions. This is what I have so far it lists out all the files but I am unsure how to get them sorted by most recently modified. This is a unique and specific question. I don't mind if this code is used or not as long as the result is code that can get the most recent file in a folder.

Code:

```
(async () => {
    var lastdownloadedimage = "";
    var pathtocheck = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads";
    var pathtocheckimage = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/ot.png";
    const testFolder = pathtocheck;
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    
    
    var lastdownloadedimage;
    var filescount = 0;
    var filename = [];
    var filedates = [];
    var filessortedbytimefromcurrentdateaccending = [];
    var files;
    
    //create a tuple for the file date and name
    var filedata = [];
    
    //fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(   filescount++);
    files = fs.readdirSync(testFolder);
    filescount = files.length;
    
    console.log(files[0]);
    

    filedates = fs.statSync(pathtocheckimage).mtime.getTime();
    filename = fs.readdirSync(testFolder);
    
    console.log(filescount);
    
    
    for(var currentfiletocheck = 0; currentfiletocheck < filescount ; currentfiletocheck++){
        //get current date
        
        //find dile that is closest to current date
        
        //use the index of that file data to find the file name
        
        //save the files name to a variable
        
        //filename[currentfiletocheck] = fs.readdirSync(testFolder)[currentfiletocheck];
        //filedates[currentfiletocheck] = fs.stats.mtime.getTime()[currentfiletocheck];
        
        //filedata[currentfiletocheck][0] = filename[currentfiletocheck];
        //filedata[currentfiletocheck][1] = filedate[currentfiletocheck];
        
            //console.log(files[currentfiletocheck]);

    }
    


    filessortedbytimefromcurrentdateaccending
        filedata.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
        });
        
        
        for (var i = 0; i < filedata.length; i++) {
          
          var filenamessortedbytimefromcurrentdateaccending = filedata[i][0];
          var filedatesortedbytimefromcurrentdateaccending = filedata[i][1];

          lastdownloadedimage = filedatesortedbytimefromcurrentdateaccending;

            // do something with key and value
        }
/*

    */
    console.log(lastdownloadedimage);


})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a different approach, and rather than gather the timestamps and sort them, I iterate over the files and compare each timestamp with the next one - keeping the timestamp and file path of the later timestamp each time.

Note that this will also check directories, so you will have to implement a filter if you want to ignore them.

```
let fs = require('fs')

let dirToCheck = '.'

let files = fs.readdirSync(dirToCheck)

let latestPath = `${dirToCheck}/${files[0]}`
let latestTimeStamp = fs.statSync(latestPath).mtime.getTime()

files.forEach(file => {

  let path = `${dirToCheck}/${file}`

  let timeStamp = fs.statSync(path).mtime.getTime()

  if (timeStamp > latestTimeStamp) {
    latestTimeStamp = timeStamp
    latestPath = path
  }
});

console.log(latestPath)
```